# Failed to connect to OpenTok(certificate verified failed)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, opentok

I created a video chat, used Opentok like this:

in `video_session_controller.rb` file.

```
require 'opentok'

def show
   @video_session = VideoSession.find_by(id: params[:id])
   opentok = OpenTok::OpenTok.new ENV['OPENTOK_API_KEY'], ENV['OPENTOK_SECRET']
   session = opentok.create_session :media_mode => :routed
   @token = session.generate_token
   @video_session.create_opentok_session(session_id: session.session_id, token: @token)
end
```

It is working on live site, but  it is not working on local machine.

In local, it shows following error.

> OpenTok::OpenTokError: Failed to connect to OpenTok. Response code:
>   SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed

How can I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: There's a known issue with older versions of Ruby with OS X and certificate verification -- could this be your case? There's a guide here that goes through the steps to repair your local machine installation: http://railsapps.github.io/openssl-certificate-verify-failed.html